# vba not recognising values in cells

Tags: excel, vba

this is my first post here I spent some time searching and banging my head against the wall looking at with fresh eyes, but I am still learning VBA and may be missing something.
I am trying to move groupings of values from the column I input them, to a table with my previous entry history so I can calculate averages.
I am using an IF condition to detect values in the entry field, but for some reason it skips to the end of the IF loop and gives me the ELSE result. 
Does anything I could be doing wrong stand out?

Thanks in advance

```
Sub MoveValuesToPrior()
'
' MoveValuesToPrior Macro
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets(2).Range("D3:D1000")) > 0 Then

Sheets(1).Range("C2:C11").Copy
Sheets(1).Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets(2).Range("D3:D1000").Copy
Sheets(2).Range("C3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets(2).Range("D3:D1000").ClearContents
Sheets(2).Range("L3:L1000").Copy
Sheets(2).Range("K3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets(2).Range("L3:L1000").ClearContents

Sheets(3).Range("D3:D1000").Copy
Sheets(3).Range("C3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets(3).Range("D3:D1000").ClearContents
Sheets(3).Range("L3:L1000").Copy
Sheets(3).Range("K3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets(3).Range("L3:L1000").ClearContents

Sheets(4).Range("D3:D1000").Copy
Sheets(4).Range("C3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets(4).Range("D3:D1000").ClearContents
Sheets(4).Range("L3:L1000").Copy
Sheets(4).Range("K3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets(4).Range("L3:L1000").ClearContents

Sheets(5).Range("D3:D1000").Copy
Sheets(5).Range("C3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets(5).Range("D3:D1000").ClearContents
Sheets(5).Range("L3:L1000").Copy
Sheets(5).Range("K3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets(5).Range("L3:L1000").ClearContents

Sheets(6).Range("D3:D1000").Copy
Sheets(6).Range("C3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets(6).Range("D3:D1000").ClearContents
Sheets(6).Range("L3:L1000").Copy
Sheets(6).Range("K3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets(6).Range("L3:L1000").ClearContents

Sheets(7).Range("D3:D1000").Copy
Sheets(7).Range("C3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets(7).Range("D3:D1000").ClearContents
Sheets(7).Range("L3:L1000").Copy
Sheets(7).Range("K3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets(7).Range("L3:L1000").ClearContents

Sheets(8).Range("D3:D1000").Copy
Sheets(8).Range("C3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets(8).Range("D3:D1000").ClearContents
Sheets(8).Range("L3:L1000").Copy
Sheets(8).Range("K3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets(8).Range("L3:L1000").ClearContents

Sheets(9).Range("D3:D1000").Copy
Sheets(9).Range("C3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets(9).Range("D3:D1000").ClearContents
Sheets(9).Range("L3:L1000").Copy
Sheets(9).Range("K3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets(9).Range("L3:L1000").ClearContents

Sheets(1).Activate

Application.CutCopyMode = False


Else: MsgBox ("The current data has already been moved to prior.")

End If


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: what's the result from `MsgBox WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets(2).Range("D3:D1000"))`?

Comment: Have you debugged this expression `WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets(2).Range("D3:D1000"))`? I mean what result do you expect and what result shows the debugger?

Comment: Is `Sheets(2)` even the sheet that you think it is?  Include a `MsgBox Sheets(2).Name` prior to your `If` statement and ensure that it returns the sheet name that you are expecting.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of the Sheets(2) method of addressing.  Adding a sheet and deleting it can change the order.  There are those who think that referring to the sheet with its codename (i.e. sheet2) is preferable, but again, modifying the book changes that.  If the sheet has a name, try using it (i.e.  Sheets ("my data") instead.  Then you know which sheet you're looking at for starters.  LOL  Coke's on you YowE3K :)

Comment: "Is Sheets(2) even the sheet that you think it is?"   I just facepalmed so hard right now, the thought that I was pointing to the wrong sheet never crossed my mind. I'll give it a shot when I get in this morning.

Comment: I was in fact pointing to the wrong sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Loops and Subroutines make your code easier to manage:

```
Sub MoveValuesToPrior()

    Dim x As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets(2).Range("D3:D1000")) > 0 Then

        'False as last argument -> don't clear source range
        CopyValues Sheets(1).Range("C2:C11"), Sheets(1).Range("B2"), False

        For x = 2 To 9
            CopyValues Sheets(x).Range("D3:D1000"), Sheets(x).Range("C3")
            CopyValues Sheets(x).Range("L3:L1000"), Sheets(x).Range("K3")
        Next x
    Else
        MsgBox ("The current data has already been moved to prior.")
    End If

    Sheets(1).Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub CopyValues(rngFrom As Range, rngTo As Range, Optional clearSource As Boolean = True)
    With rngFrom
        rngTo.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
        If clearSource Then .ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like I have a few things to try this morning, thanks for the tips!